# Regression proof for decomposition of sums of squares

Tags: regression, proof, sum

[image: Question]

I got as far as distributing the summation across the Left Side so that I have:

$$ \sum_i y_i^2 - \sum_i 2 y_i \bar{y} + \sum_i \bar{y}^2 $$

Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

A very common trick in these situations where you have an expression on the left and an expression on the right involving a term that doesn't appear on the left is to either add and subtract or multiply and divide by that term, depending on context.  Here you can try

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar{y})^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i + \hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i) (\hat{y}_i - \bar{y}) .
\end{align}

Now we just need to show that the rightmost term equals zero.  You should be able to convince yourself that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i) = 0$ by plugging in the formula for $\hat{y}_i$ so we only need to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i) \hat{y}_i = 0$,

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i) \hat{y}_i &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i) (\bar{y} - \hat{\beta}_1 \bar{x} + \hat{\beta}_1 x_i) \\
&= \hat{\beta}_1 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i) (x_i - \bar{x})
\end{align}

and the remaining steps can be found in my answer to this question: [Proof that $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ in simple linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236207/proof-that-hat-sigma2-is-an-unbiased-estimator-of-sigma2-in-simple-lin).

Comment: So, I followed your logic and got the first two parts of the right side. But I can't figure out how the rightmost term equals zero. I know that 
sum(yi-ybar)=0, but does the same principle apply for yhat?

Comment: I actually had some typos in my original answer, sorry about that.  Yes you should be able to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y}_i) = 0$.  Anyways, I showed the rest of the steps from there.